# How to accept Rating value of RateController as string in swift

Tags: swift

I am fetching rating data from API as Array of String. But "ratingcontrol.rating" value only accept the Int value . so while population the rating in custom tableview cell It gives error. HOW TO RESOLVE IT?

Rating Declaration:

```
   var Ratings:Array< String > = Array < String >()
```

Now I am fetching data from Api as:

```
        var json: NSArray!
        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? NSArray
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

   self.Ratings = json.valueForKey("rate") as! Array<String>
       print(self.Ratings)
```

It successfully show me the value from Api. Now I am populating it into the customtableviewcell.

```
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
              let cell =  
            tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReviewCustomCell", 
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewCustomCell

             **cell.ratingControl.rating = Ratings[indexPath.row]**
    return cell
}
```

The above bold one shows error as "Cant accept value of type string to int". 
Anyone give some idea to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to take the rating value as array of integer instead array of string.

```
 // var Ratings:Array< String > = Array < String >()
   var Ratings:Array<Int > = Array<Int >()
```

Check if it works or not

Comment: I have tried this one too but still another error there regarding datatypes mismatch.